# Facebook log in on weebly

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, authentication

Can someone give me a step by step how to implement Facebook's login plugin onto a weebly site? Where does the SDK go in HTML/CSS? Or does it all go in an embedded code? I have been stuck on this trying everything please show me what code goes where. I have done research and it seems using the javascript is the only way to go. Thank you!

---

Yes I have tried the steps on facebook right now I have this. This is entered in the splash.html page in Html/CSS.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{myappID}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then I have this in an embedded code on the actual splash page content:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=246238232244147&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false"   data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

This is for the button, but the button only shows up when I am designing or building the page and not when I publish it. Thank you!

Comment: So I suspect/hope you tried the javascript login process as described on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0) and encountered some error? Can you document what failed when you follow the tutorial as provided by Facebook?

Comment: Yes please take a look thank you very much!